# Solving a system of equations with sparse data

Tags: machine-learning, regression, algorithms, genetic

I am attempting to solve a set of equations which has 40 independent variables (x1, ..., x40) and one dependent variable (y). The total number of equations (number of rows) is ~300, and I want to solve for the set of 40 coefficients that minimizes the total sum-of-square error between y and the predicted value.

My problem is that the matrix is very sparse and I do not know the best way to solve the system of equations with sparse data. An example of the dataset is shown below:

```
   y    x1  x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 ... x40
87169   14  0  1  0  0  2  ... 0 
46449   0   0  4  0  1  4  ... 12
846449  0   0  0  0  0  3  ... 0
....
```

I am currently using a Genetic Algorithm to solve this and the results are coming out 
with roughly a factor of two difference between observed and expected.

Can anyone suggest different methods or techniques which are capable of solving a set of equations with sparse data.

Comment: Typo in the title: spare => sparse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is the case of **multiple linear regression with sparse data** (*sparse regression*). Assuming that, I hope you will find the following **resources** useful.

1) NCSU **lecture slides on sparse regression** with overview of algorithms, notes, formulas, graphics and references to literature: http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/people/zhou/courses/st810/notes/lect23sparse.pdf

2) `R` ecosystem offers many **packages**, useful for sparse regression analysis, including:

- **Matrix** (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix)
- **SparseM** (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparseM)
- **MatrixModels** (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatrixModels)
- **glmnet** (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet)
- **flare** (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flare)

3) A blog post with an **example of sparse regression solution**, based on `SparseM`: http://aleph-nought.blogspot.com/2012/03/multiple-linear-regression-with-sparse.html

4) A blog post on using **sparse matrices in R**, which includes a **primer** on using `glmnet`: http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r

5) **More examples and some discussion** on the topic can be found on **StackOverflow**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169371/large-scale-regression-in-r-with-a-sparse-feature-matrix

**UPDATE** (based on your comment):

If you're trying to solve an LP problem with constraints, you may find this **theoretical paper** useful: http://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/papers/gmsw84.pdf.

Also, check R package **limSolve**: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/limSolve. And, in general, check packages in *CRAN Task View* **"Optimization and Mathematical Programming"**: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html.

Finally, check the book **"Using R for Numerical Analysis in Science and Engineering"** (by Victor A. Bloomfield). It has a section on solving systems of equations, represented by **sparse matrices** (section 5.7, pages 99-104), which includes examples, based on some of the above-mentioned packages: http://books.google.com/books?id=9ph_AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=r+limsolve+sparse+matrix&source=bl&ots=PHDE8nXljQ&sig=sPi4n5Wk0M02ywkubq7R7KD_b04&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FZjiU-ioIcjmsATGkYDAAg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=r%20limsolve%20sparse%20matrix&f=false.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I am hesitant to classify the problem as sparse regression since I am not really trying to model and predict but rather solve for a set of coefficients. The reason I am using Genetic Algorithms is because I can also employ constraints on the equation. If no other answers come through I will gladly accept this though.

Comment: @mike1886: My pleasure! I have updated my answer, based on your comment. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

[Aleksandr's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/918/2853) is completely correct.

However, the way the question is posed implies that this is a straightforward ordinary least squares regression question: minimizing the sum of squared residuals between a dependent variable and a linear combination of predictors.

Now, while there may be many zeros in your design matrix, your system as such is not overly large: 300 observations on 40 predictors is no more than medium-sized. You can run such a regression using R without any special efforts for sparse data. Just use the `lm()` command (for "linear model"). Use `?lm` to see the help page. And note that `lm` will by default silently add a constant column of ones to your design matrix (the intercept) - include a `-1` on the right hand side of your formula to suppress this. Overall, assuming all your data (and nothing else) is in a `data.frame` called `foo`, you can do this:

```
model <- lm(y~.-1,data=foo)
```

And then you can look at parameter estimates etc. like this:

```
summary(model)
residuals(model)
```

*If* your system is *much* larger, say on the order of 10,000 observations and hundreds of predictors, looking at specialized sparse solvers as per [Aleksandr's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/918/2853) may start to make sense.

Finally, in your comment to [Aleksandr's answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/918/2853), you mention constraints on your equation. If that is actually your key issue, there are ways to calculate constrained least squares in R. I personally like `pcls()` in the `mgcv` package. Perhaps you want to edit your question to include the type of constraints (box constraints, nonnegativity constraints, integrality constraints, linear constraints, ...) you face?

Comment: Stephan, I appreciate your kind words! Upvoted your nice answer. You might be interested in the update I made to my answer, based on comment by the question's author.