# Nearest neighbors search for very high dimensional data

Tags: machine-learning, distributed, map-reduce, dimensionality-reduction

I have a big sparse matrix of users and items they like (in the order of 1M users and 100K items, with a very low level of sparsity). I'm exploring ways in which I could perform kNN search on it. Given the size of my dataset and some initial tests I performed, my assumption is that the method I will use will need to be either parallel or distributed. So I'm considering two classes of possible solutions: one that is either available (or implementable in a reasonably easy way) on a single multicore machine, the other on a Spark cluster, i.e. as a MapReduce program. Here are three broad ideas that I considered:

- Assuming a cosine similarity metric, perform the full multiplication of the normalized matrix by its transpose (implemented as a sum of outer products)
- Using locality-sensitive hashing (LSH)
- Reducing first the dimensionality of the problem with a PCA

I'd appreciate any thoughts or advices about possible other ways in which I could tackle this problem.

Comment: I've just been investigating this area and wrote a blog post about what I found.  I used an LSH, but I think my sparsity level was higher than you are looking for.  http://tttv-engineering.tumblr.com/post/109569205836/scaling-similarity

Answer (score 17):

I hope that the following **resources** might get you additional **ideas** toward solving the problem:

1) Research paper **"Efficient K-Nearest Neighbor Join Algorithms for High Dimensional Sparse Data"**: http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2807

2) Class project paper **"Recommendation System Based on Collaborative Filtering"** (Stanford University): http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2008/Wen-RecommendationSystemBasedOnCollaborativeFiltering.pdf

3) Project for the **Netflix Prize Competition (*k-NN*-based)**: http://cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0910/netflixprize/final_results/knn/index.html

4) Research paper **"Hubs in Space: Popular Nearest Neighbors in High-Dimensional Data"** on the *curse of dimensionality* phenomenon and its relation to *machine learning*, in general, and *k-NN algorithm*, in particular: http://jmlr.org/papers/volume11/radovanovic10a/radovanovic10a.pdf

5) **Software for sparse k-NN classification** (free, but appears not to be open source - might clarify with authors): http://www.autonlab.org/autonweb/10408.html

6) Several **discussion threads** on *StackOverflow*:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333092/knn-with-big-sparse-matrices-in-python
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18164348/efficient-nearest-neighbour-search-for-sparse-matrices
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085990/scipy-sparse-distance-matrix-scikit-or-scipy
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472681/handling-incomplete-data-data-sparsity-in-knn
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560218/computing-sparse-pairwise-distance-matrix-in-r (unlike all previous discussions, which refer to `Python`, this one refers to `R` ecosystem)

7) Pay attention to *GraphLab*, an open source **parallel framework for machine learning** (http://select.cs.cmu.edu/code/graphlab), which supports *parallel clustering* via `MapReduce` model: http://select.cs.cmu.edu/code/graphlab/clustering.html

You might also check my answer here on Data Science StackExchange on *sparse regression* for links to relevant `R` packages and `CRAN Task View` pages: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/918/2452.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working on collaborative filtering you should pose the problem as a low-rank matrix approximation, wherein both the users are items are co-embedded into the same low-dimensionality space. Similarity search will be much simpler then. I recommend using LSH, as you suggested. Another fruitful avenue for dimensionality reduction not yet mentioned is [random projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_projection).

Answer (score 2):

You should use : [PySparNN](https://github.com/facebookresearch/pysparnn), a recent implementation by Facebook in python which is bloody fast. It is also easy to use.