# Classification of goods by category

Tags: classification

i have labeled data with goods like:
"Double chamber refrigerator Hitachi R-WB 482 PU2 GBW".

I need to predict category like: laptops, household appliances etc.

How can i do this?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data/

Comment: Names of categories and goods in Russian.
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b2XT1MdnJnsnIWhhppN_OXo0bNtveV2G

Comment: Can you just attach a screenshot in the question itself so it will help other users also..Can't understand Russian though

Comment: There is no need to understand Russian, words are words in any language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Random forests should be able to handle categorical values natively so look for a different implementation so you don't have to encode all of those features and use up all your memory..
- [XGBoost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html)
- [Dimensionality Reduction](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/4942/35644)
- [CatBoost](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/08/catboost-automated-categorical-data/)
- [Hierarchical Clustering Using Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html)
- [Target Encoding](https://www.kaggle.com/ogrellier/python-target-encoding-for-categorical-features)